# Как вызвать событие click в selenium если у кнопки нет id

Tags: python, selenium

Всем привет. Как вызвать событие click (нажатие на кнопку) в selenium в python, если у нее отсутствует id.

Comment: Вы можете использовать xPath или class. В Selenium не обязательно использовать поиск по ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поиск кнопки через класс:

```py
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "login-btn")
button.click()
```

Поиск кнопки через её текст (работает со ссылками):

```py
button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Login")
button.click()
```

Через CCS-атрибуты виджета кнопки:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-test='login-btn']")
button.click()
```

Через XPath атрибуты (через путь в XML структуре, которую использует HTML)

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-test=login-btn]")
button.click()
```